# Android app crashes on installing @react-native-firebase/messaging (v6)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

Note :Console shows success build, so not able to track the error of crash.
PS: @react-native-firebase/app already installed
Google services have been added in to build.gradle and app/build.gradle , google-services.json has been added.
Attached my android/build.gradle
[image]

Comment: Share the error log.